# What is the The grammatical subject in the given sentences?

Tags: syntax, literature, antecedents

> One comfort that she had under the Ordeal by General was more sustaining to her, and made her more grateful than to a less devoted and affectionate spirit, not habituated to her struggles and sacrifices, might appear quite reasonable; and, indeed, it may often be observed in life, that spirits like Little Dorrit do not appear to reason half as carefully as the folks who get the better of them.
> [Source - Little Dorrit, Dickens (1857)](https://www.dickens-online.info/little-dorrit-page339.html)

What is the grammatical subject of "might appear quite reasonable" in the preceding sentence?

Comment: This question requires more research to have been done. What do you think is the subject? Why do you doubt your own conclusion?

Comment: If she had been less grateful. (She was 'more grateful than...might appear reasonable')

Comment: The overall subject is ***One comfort,*** - a comfort that *...was more sustaining and made her more grateful than ... might appear reasonable* .

Comment: There are two main clauses and therefore two subjects. Look for the coordinator "and" to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

Dickens... never write one word when 25 would be more confusing....

He is doing lots in this sentence. I will cut out some of the optional elements, and rearrange to put the prepositional phrase "to a less devoted..." in a more reasonable place. I get

> One comfort:
>
> - was more sustaining to her, and
> - made her more grateful than might appear reasonable to a less devoted spirit.

Now, there is no explicit subject for "might appear".  Implicitly it is "her gratitude for the one comfort" that might not appear reasonable. And this is the implied subject.  We can find other simpler constructions along the same lines as this:

> EU diplomats have made more progress on revising the Maastricht Treaty than might appear at first sight.

Again, there is no explicit subject for "might appear", implicitly "the progress on revising the treaty might not appear at first sight."